# Get Ports grep using netstat -v

Tags: shell, grep

I want to get a list of ports of the established connections using `netstat -v grep`.

I am trying this:

```
sudo netstat -v | grep "ESTABLISHED" | cut -d: -f5
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
netstat -v| grep "ESTABLISHED"| awk '{print $5}' | cut -d ":" -f2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with `$5` and `$4`:

```
netstat -v | awk '/ESTABLISHED/ {split($5, array, ":"); print array[2]}'
```